# SimpleXML returns an object instead of a string

Tags: php, simplexml

I have some XML that looks like this:

```
<Body>
    <RESULT>
        <SUCCESS>true</SUCCESS>
        <SESSIONID>42</SESSIONID>
        <SESSION_ENCODING>;jsessionid=42</SESSION_ENCODING>
    </RESULT>
</Body>
```

SimpleXML parses it, in this way:

```
$obj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStringAsAbove);
$this->sessionId = $obj->Body->RESULT->SESSIONID;
```

and the result is this:

```
[sessionId:protected] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => 42
    )
```

What I need  is this:

```
[sessionId:protected] => 42
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cast it to a string (or an int) to get the contents of the `<SESSIONID>` tag:

```
$this->sessionId = (string) $obj->Body->RESULT->SESSIONID;
```

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, SimpleXMLElement can be a pain when you need a value instead of an object.

As per the previous answer, you can cast the XML part you want, or use one of the following methods:

From the ops example, to get an integer you can use intval():

`$this->sessionId = intval($obj->Body->RESULT->SESSIONID);`

As of (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7) you can also use the SimpleXMLElement::__toString method to get a string;

https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php

```
$this->sessionIdasString = $obj->Body->RESULT->SESSIONID->__toString();
```